# Show my own ads using AdMob?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have integrated AdMob in my application. Is it possible to show my own ads using Admob? If not, then what is the best alternative?

Comment: buy ad-space from google and hope you see it or use an ImageView to show your own image (and link onClick to some WWW).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes! Ad Mob allows you the option of displaying your own ads using the "**House Ad Campaigns**" option.

That being said, if by "*show my own ads using Admob??*", you mean display custom ads, then you would probably have to get in advertisers individually and display them using (as @zapl mentioned in the comments) ImageView or something on those lines.

Comment: @Peterdk: I know. Since the question is kinda vague, at least I thought it is, I have added the bit about House Ads. The last paragraph covers what I would do if I needed to show my own ads.

Comment: You are wrong in the sense of: you state that your house ads display in other apps and never in your own app. The opposite is true.

Comment: Okay. Apologies for the misinformation. Will remove that bit.

Comment: @SiddharthLele hi, is that possible to display any number of banners (own adds) and change the banner image for every 5secs randomly by admob?

Comment: Are we allowed to advertise our sponsora using ImageView and WebView?

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can. The feature is called [House Ads](https://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1619751)