# Showing In House Ads in my own application and device in which the app is installed using Google AdMob SDK

Tags: android, ios, sdk, admob

So the question itself describes what I want to achieve.
I have a vendor who is interested to host his Ads in my iOS/Android application.
For that, I created custom Ad (House Ad) in Google AdMob and followed the steps described here:
[Create a house ad campaign](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3210442?hl=en&rd=1&authuser=1#survey=true)

I also googled about such a situation and found two relevant posts on SO as shown in the following links:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26184079/how-to-implement-my-own-custom-advertisement-in-my-own-android-application-using) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281008/show-my-own-adds-using-admob)

I copied the Ad Unit IDs in my iOS/Android apps but the Ads that I created are not showing in my device/app.
Does Google AdMob displays Ads as per its own Rules and Policies? e.g. Geographic location of device, Traffic of other popular advertisers and so on.
I just want to display these in House Ads in my App.
Please lead me in the right direction..

Comment: What solution did you came up with?

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not get resolved. We gave up. Do you have any suggestions/recommendation for this?

Comment: Did you follow this? https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3210442?hl=en&rd=1

Comment: I have mixed result. Sometimes house ads show, but rarely. I tried setting eCPM to 2$ and enabled AdMob optimization. I also tried to enable AdMob network only ofr some 3rd world country and disabled showing ads from them in other countries. No luck.